# ROS Installation on Windows 10 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ros

I am trying to install ROS on my Windows 10 laptop through ubuntu 18.04 from the windows market (I am not interested in changing over to Linux) and I have a couple of questions. First, when I put the following into Ubuntu:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

nothing happened I want to make sure that that was right.

After that, I tried to set up my keys but I kept getting the message that connecting dirmngr failed, the IPC connect call failed, and No dirmngr. This was after uninstalling and reinstalling dirmngr, disabling my firewalls (which my teacher said to do), and running as an administrator.

How can I get around this particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, how did you install ubuntu? At the moment I'm thinking you are using either a virtual machine like VMware or VirtualBox, or you installed Ubuntu next to your windows 10.

The first option is fine if you not intend to run some heavy simulation with gazebo or do to do image analysis.

Now to your first question:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

After this command there should be a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`. You can check its existence and its content with:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

The output in my case is (xenial can differ, the rest should be the same):

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main
```

Your second question is a little bit harder:
It seems you have a bug related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3286). Here is a workaround.
Run this instead:

```
curl -sL "http://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0x421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116&op=get" | sudo apt-key add
```

After this, you should be able to follow the installation manual again.
http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu